# How to get the dictionary with the highest value in a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries. Is it possible to get the dictionary or its index that has the highest score key value? Here is the list:

```
 lst = [{'name': 'tom', 'score': 5}, 
        {'name': 'jerry', 'score': 10},
        {'name': 'jason', 'score': 8}]
```

It should return:

```
{'name': 'jerry', 'score': 10}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The built-in function, [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) takes an optional `key` function, which can be supplied in the form of a [`lambda`:](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms)

```
>>> max(lst, key=lambda x:x['score'])
{'score': 10, 'name': 'jerry'}
```

Answer (score 9):

An alternative to using a `lambda` for the `key` argument to `max`, is `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
max(lst, key=itemgetter('score'))
```

Answer (score 3):

My preferred way would be to use a lambda to extract the score:

```
>>> lst= [{'name':'tom','score':5},{'name':'jerry','score':10},{'name':'jason','score':8}]
>>> max(lst, key=lambda d: d['score'])
{'score': 10, 'name': 'jerry'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst= [{'name':'tom','score':5},{'name':'jerry','score':10},{'name':'jason','score':8}]

print max(lst, key=lambda x: x['score'])
```